# What encoding is this?

Tags: c++, encodings, unknown-data

[image: weird stuff]

This is a picture of the encoded code. I'm just wondering what is the encoding that it is using.

Comment: you are probably opening a binary file in a text viewer

Comment: I believe it would add more context to provide the `strings` and `file` outputs, they may give some strings and types that are relevant to some file formats or encryption/encoding scheme.
Maybe you can give `binwalk` as try as well in case it had multiple embedded resources in one binary.

Comment: Post a link to the file please

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a Mach-O executable (`__cstring`), but opening a binary file in a text editor won't give lot of info.

It's basically a guess game at this stage. Use the `file` command on this file to make sure it's an executable and disassemble it maybe?